# EXCEPT query to get info year to date

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor

I have a table which holds account transactions for each account, I’ve written a query that tells me when an account has paid one month, but not the next based on the Parameter MonthID (from cal lookup table)

```
DECLARE @MonthID INT
SET @MonthID = 128

SELECT AccountNo, Emp,
     FROM Table1 AS t INNER JOIN 
                tblcal AS cl ON t.date = cl.Date
                     WHERE cl.MonthID = @MonthID
EXCEPT
SELECT AccountNo, Emp,
     FROM Table1 AS t INNER JOIN 
                tblcal AS cl ON t.date = cl.Date
                     WHERE cl.MonthID = @MonthID+1
```

Query works great for getting the records for the specified month however I need to look at getting this for every month of the year and have no idea how to factor that requirement in?

Is a cursor the best way for doing this? I’ve read a lot of negative’s about cursors?

At the moment it returns data like:

```
MonthID   | SkippedPay
 128      |  12445
```

(as i perform an count on the account numbers)

What i need is to get it for the last 12 months, so the same as above but with 12 months of data, this is what is making me think of a cursor to go through each month and populate a table?

```
MonthID   | SkippedPay
 128      |  12445
 129      |   1256
```

Comment: Can you update your answer and provide an example of how you want the results to be returned?

Comment: Not sure why you need the EXCEPT in the original query - can you explain?

Comment: @Rikalous the query checks for a payment in the month specified then looks to see if a payment was received the following month and returns rows where there isnt any payments the following month.

Comment: Ok, if you can conceive of a way of doing it with a cursor then I would go ahead and do it. A set based approach in this case may be quite complicated. Cursors are discouraged because they are slower and less performant than set operations but sometimes they are the most expedient solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following approach: 
You `left join` the dataset of one month against the data for the following month and return the rows in which there is no corresponding data in the following month.

```
DECLARE @MonthID INT
SET @MonthID = 128

SELECT MonthA.AccountNo, MonthA.Emp FROM 
(SELECT AccountNo, Emp, cl.MonthID as [Month]
     FROM Table1 AS t INNER JOIN 
                tblcal AS cl ON t.date = cl.Date
                     WHERE cl.MonthID >= @MonthID-12 and cl.MonthID <= @MonthID) AS MonthA
LEFT JOIN                    
(SELECT AccountNo, Emp, cl.MonthID as [Month]
     FROM Table1 AS t INNER JOIN 
                tblcal AS cl ON t.date = cl.Date
WHERE cl.MonthID >= @MonthID-11 and  and cl.MonthID <= @MonthID+1) AS MonthB on MonthA.AccountNo = MonthB.AccountNo AND MonthA.Emp = MonthB.Emp AND (MonthA.[Month]+1) = Monthb.[Month]
WHERE MonthB.AccountNo IS NULL
```

p.s.: You got a syntax error in your query: "Emp," with no following field.